# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Problem when use for generic types

Tags: c#, generics, json.net, deserialization

I'm using this code to deserialize my json data to list of objects as follow :

```
public static List<T> DeserializeListFromTempData<T>(HttpContext context, string strName)
        {
            List<T> lstResult = null;

            var iTempData = HelperMethods.GetTempData(context);
            var tmp = iTempData.Peek(strName);
            if (tmp != null)
            {
                lstResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(tmp.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
            }

            return lstResult;
        }
```

And usage :

```
List<DefaultVisitProductDetails> lstPackageDetails = HelperMethods.DeserializeListFromTempData<DefaultVisitProductDetails>(this.HttpContext, "_lstPackageDetails");
```

The above codes works correctly. However, when i use it inside another generic method as follow :

```
public static void AttachDetailsListToDbContext<T, TDetails, TField>(HttpContext context, string strName, DbContext dbContext, object masterObjectGraph, Expression<Func<T, TDetails>> details, Expression<Func<T, TField>> field, TField value, InternalHelperAction action) where T : class
        {
List<TDetails> lstPackageDetails = HelperMethods.DeserializeListFromTempData<TDetails>(context, strName);
...
}
```

i'm facing the following problem :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[EFCoreTest.Models.DefaultVisitProductDetails]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.

Where is the problem & how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your string is not an array.you cant deserialize { } object to list. You need to have an array representation

Comment: My string is just a name of object which stored in TempData, i don't use it in deserialization.

Comment: Doesn't your error message tell you everything there is? It seems like the json you feed it isn't formatted as list but rather as object (so with `{ }` instead of `[ ]`). Try to print out the json before you get to it and see what it actually is. You could also just step through with a debugger to check the same thing. Then in case it is actually an array (`[ ]`), post the json. Maybe we can help you then.